# Electromagnetism in spacetime with 2-times split-signature $(+,+,-,-)$ metric

Tags: electromagnetism, spacetime, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions

Maxwell's equations can easily be generalized to any $(m,n)$-spacetime. Is there any material analyzing what such a theory will look like?

Note that a particle still moves in spacetime forming a line. It's velocity has four components $(\gamma_sc, \gamma_tc, v_x, v_y)$, where $(v_x, v_y)$ make up the ordinary velocity in 2-space. But there are now a direction to the temporal component. This breaks causality, but from pure mathematical considerations it seems fine.

The electromagnetic field breaks up into *three* parts: a magnetic field $B$ that is a scalar, as we would expect from the two space dimensions; an electric field $E$ that is a weird bilinear function (or a $2\times2$ matrix) instead of a vector; a new strange scalar field (tempo-magnetic?). The 4-Lorentz force also breaks into three parts: The usual Lorentz force that just rotates the spatial velocity; an electric force that is a bit complicated; and a tempo-Lorentz force that steers the $(\gamma_sc, \gamma_tc)$ component of the velocity.

I would like to see if there is any further analysis on this matter, especially concerning the classical limit $c \to \infty$, and a "uni-temporal limit" where most of the matter in the universe has $\gamma_s \approx 0$ and $\gamma_t \approx 1$, effectively moving in just one temporal direction.

Comment: You may try to consult: "Geometry of Zero Signature Space-times", Marc Henneaux, Bull.Soc.Math.Belg. 31 (1979) 47-63 . This can also be of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401016v1 "Is the Lorentz signature of the metric of spacetime electromagnetic in origin?"